# Iterate over unknown repeated protobuf field with FieldDescriptor

Tags: c#, iterator, protocol-buffers

I am trying to write a generalized method to iterate through a protobuf message and basically create an object tree.

So far I have

```
IMessage message = new Message() as IMessage;
foreach (FieldDescriptor field in message.Descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder())
            {
                if (field.FieldType == Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldType.Message)
                {
                    if (field.IsRepeated)
                    {
                        // How to do this?
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Children.Add(new MessageNode(field, (IMessage)field.Accessor.GetValue(message)));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Children.Add(new FieldNode(field, message));
                }
           }
```

Works fine except for repeated fields (and probably the same problem will crop up for Map fields).

If I do `field.Accessor.GetValue(message)` for the repeated field, I get an `object[RepeatedField<T>]` with `T` being some nested message. However, I cannot iterate over something of type `object`.
I tried casting object to `RepeatedField<IMessage>` but this just returns 0.

Is there any way to iterate over a repeated field without knowing the type inside? I would just need an `IMessage` pointer to the objects inside, from there I can work with the `Descriptor` in `IMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how blind I have been in the last two days trying to solve this...

Right in the documentation for `GetValue` of the `Accessor` it says

> For repeated values, this will be an IList implementation. For map values, this will be an IDictionary implementation.

So yeah, `IList d = field.Accessor.GetValue(message) as IList;` does the trick and provides an iterable collection of the repeated field.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916926/2149955), as per [the protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/reflection/i-field-accessor#getvalue) `field.Accessor.GetValue(protobufMessage)` will return you an `IList` for repeated fields and an `IDictionary` for map fields.

Here is some code I wrote that iterates recursively through a protobuf message using the field descriptors. It may be a useful starting point for doing other operations instead of printing.

```
    public static void PrintProtobufMessage(IMessage protobufMessage)
    {
        if (protobufMessage == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var field in protobufMessage.Descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder())
        {
            if (field.IsMap)
            {
                // for map fields, the field type is always a MapField, inside of which are contained a keyField and valueField
                //var keyField = field.MessageType.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder()[0];
                var valueField = field.MessageType.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder()[1];
                IDictionary mapFields = field.Accessor.GetValue(protobufMessage) as IDictionary;
                if (mapFields != null)
                {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry mapField in mapFields)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Iterating Map, Field {0} ({1}): Key {2}:", field.FieldNumber, field.Name, mapField.Key);
                        if (valueField.FieldType == Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldType.Message)
                        {
                            PrintProtobufMessage(mapField.Value as IMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PrintProtobufField(valueField, mapField.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (field.IsRepeated)
            {
                IList repeatedFieldValues = field.Accessor.GetValue(protobufMessage) as IList;
                if (repeatedFieldValues != null)
                {
                    foreach (var repeatedFieldValue in repeatedFieldValues)
                    {
                        // for repeated fields, the field type represents each element in the list, handle them accordingly
                        if (field.FieldType == Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldType.Message)
                        {
                            PrintProtobufMessage(repeatedFieldValue as IMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PrintProtobufField(field, repeatedFieldValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.FieldType == Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldType.Message)
                {
                    var fieldValue = field.Accessor.GetValue(protobufMessage);
                    PrintProtobufMessage(fieldValue as IMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    PrintProtobufField(field, protobufMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintProtobufField(FieldDescriptor field, IMessage protobufMessage)
    {                   
        var fieldValue = field.Accessor.GetValue(protobufMessage);
        PrintProtobufField(field, fieldValue);
    }

    public static void PrintProtobufField(FieldDescriptor field, object fieldValue)
    {
        if (fieldValue != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Field {0} ({1}): {2}",
                field.FieldNumber,
                field.Name,
                fieldValue
            );
        }
    }
```